# Transform a recursive json object to another json object

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

Need help with transforming a recursive json object into another json object.

My input object looks like this:

```
{  
  person: 
  {
       name: 'John Henry',
       age: 63
  },
  children: 
  [
        {
            person:
            {
                name: 'Paul Henry',
                age: 40
            },
            children: 
            [
                {
                    person:
                    {
                        name: 'Tom Henry',
                        age: 10
                    }
                }
                {
                    person:
                    {
                        name: 'Mike Henry',
                        age: 12
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            person:
            {
                name: 'Wilson Henry',
                age: 30
            }
        },
        {
            person:
            {
                name: 'Richard Henry',
                age: 59
            }
        }
  ]
}
```

The output I want is:

```
[{
          name: 'John Henry',
          attributes: { age: 63 },
          children: 
          [
            {
                name: 'Paul Henry',
                attributes: { age: 40 },
                children: [
                  {
                      name: 'Tom Henry',
                      attributes: { age: 10 }
                  },
                  {
                      name: 'Mike Henry',
                      attributes: { age: 12 }
                  }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Wilson Henry',
                attributes: { age: 30 }
            },
            {
                name: 'Richard Henry',
                attributes: { age: 59 }
            }
         ]
}];
```

This is what I have tried so far, but got stuck at the recursion part. Not sure how to bring everything together.:

```
var tree = {};
var getFamilyTree = function (input) {

  tree.name = input.person.name;
  tree.attributes = { 'age': input.person.age };
  tree.children = [];

  input.children.forEach(function (child) {
      //not sure how to recursively go through the child nodes.
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new output object at the start of the function.

For each child, call `getFamilyTree()` again on the child - it will be the new `input`. Append the result of that call to your new children list.

Return your newly-created object.

Something like:

```
function getFamilyTree(input)
{
  var newb = { 'attributes': {} };

  for ( f in input.person )    // we may have attributes other than "age"
    if (f == 'name')
      newb.name = input.person[f];
    else
      newb.attributes[f] = input.person[f];

  if (input.children && input.children.length)
    {
      newb.children = [];

      for ( var i = 0; i < input.children.length; ++i )
        {
          newb.children.push(getFamilyTree(input.children[i]));
        }
    }

  return newb;
}
```

```js
var orig = {  
  person: 
  {
       name: 'John Henry',
       age: 63
  },
  children: 
  [
        {
            person:
            {
                name: 'Paul Henry',
                age: 40
            },
            children: 
            [
                {
                    person:
                    {
                        name: 'Tom Henry',
                        age: 10
                    }
                },
                {
                    person:
                    {
                        name: 'Mike Henry',
                        age: 12
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            person:
            {
                name: 'Wilson Henry',
                age: 30
            }
        },
        {
            person:
            {
                name: 'Richard Henry',
                age: 59
            }
        }
  ]
};


function getFamilyTree(o)
{
  var newb = { 'attributes': {} };
  
  for ( f in o.person )    // we may have attributes other than "age"
    if (f == 'name')
      newb.name = o.person[f];
    else
      newb.attributes[f] = o.person[f];
  
  if (o.children && o.children.length)
    {
      newb.children = [];
      
      for ( var i = 0; i < o.children.length; ++i )
        {
          newb.children.push(getFamilyTree(o.children[i]));
        }
    }
  
  return newb;
}


console.log( JSON.stringify( getFamilyTree(orig), null, "  " ) );
```